# How to append text only once in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to append text next to each matched link?

```
for (var i = 0; i < author.length; i++) {
  var adminID = author[i]["href"].match(/\/users\/(\d+)/g);
  for (var j = 0; j < userID.length; j++) {
    if (adminID == userID[j]) {
      $(`a[href*="${userID[j]}"]`).append('<span>text</span>');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you show the values of `author` and `userID`, and how you want the HTML to change?

Answer (score 0):

Ad a flag to state it has been appended

```
for (var i = 0; i < author.length; i++) {
  var adminID = author[i]["href"].match(/\/users\/(\d+)/g);
  var appended = false;
  for (var j = 0; j < userID.length; j++) {
    if (adminID == userID[j] && !appended) {
      appended = true;
      $(`a[href*="${userID[j]}"]`).append('<span>text</span>');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `break` to end the inner loop?

Comment: What if the outer loop has duplicate `adminID`? It will match the same ID multiple times.

Comment: I have no idea what his data set is or if he is looking to do extra logic.

Comment: Yeah, I asked for clarification above. I don't consider this clear enough to answer well.

Answer (score 0):

Just `break` afterwards:

```
for (var i = 0; i < author.length; i++) {
  var adminID = author[i]["href"].match(/\/users\/(\d+)/g);
  for (var j = 0; j < userID.length; j++) {
    if (adminID == userID[j]) {
      $(`a[href*="${userID[j]}"]`).append('<span>text</span>');
      break;
    }
  }
}
```